# append a value to $(this) in order to refer to another element

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery is it possible to append another value to $(this) in order to refer for example to a child element?
What I need is something like this:

`$(this + " div").remove(".cover");`

But the syntax `+ " div"` doesn't work, is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Comment: I think you want `$('div', this)` (`this` being the context in which to look for the `div`) - http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Comment: @billyonecan yeah it worked thanks :) if you want post it as a solution and i'll accept as soon as i can!

Comment: As a side note, `$('div', this)` is shorthand for the answer that Curt gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `this` as the context in which to look for the `div`, eg:

`$('div', this).remove('.cover');`

Which is equivelant to `$(this).find('div').remove('.cover')`

#### From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context):

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so  `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to  `$( this ).find( "span" )`.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to find children `div` elements of *this* element, and therefore you can use:

```
$(this).find("div").remove(".cover");
```